# Migrate Secrets from SecretManager in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

Hi I have my secrets in Secretmanager in one project and want to know how to copy them or migrate them to other project.

Is there a mechanism to do it smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

edited according to John Hanley's comment

I just had to deal with something similar myself, and came up with a simple bash script that does what I need. I run Linux.
there are some prerequisites:

1. download the gcloud cli for your OS.
2. get the list of secrets you want to migrate (you can do it by setting up the gcloud with the source project `gcloud config set project [SOURCE_PROJECT]`, and then running `gcloud secrets list`)
3. then once you have the list, convert it textually to a list in
   format `"secret_a" "secret_b" ...`
4. the last version of each secret is taken, so it must not be in a "disabled" state, or it won't be able to move it.

then you can run:

```
$(gcloud config set project [SOURCE_PROJECT])
declare -a secret_array=("secret_a" "secret_b" ...)
for i in "${secret_array[@]}"
do
    SECRET_NAME="${i}_env_file"
    SECRET_VALUE=$(gcloud secrets versions access "latest" --secret=${SECRET_NAME})
    echo $SECRET_VALUE > secret_migrate
    $(gcloud secrets create ${SECRET_NAME} --project [TARGET_PROJECT] --data-file=secret_migrate)
done
rm secret_migrate
```

what this script does, is set the project to the source one, then get the secrets, and one by one save it to file, and upload it to the target project.
the file is rewritten for each secret and deleted at the end.
you need to replace the secrets array (`secret_array`), and the project names (`[SOURCE_PROJECT]`, `[TARGET_PROJECT]`) with your own data.

I used this version below, which also sets a different name, and labels according to the secret name:

```
$(gcloud config set project [SOURCE_PROJECT])
declare -a secret_array=("secret_a" "secret_b" ...)
for i in "${secret_array[@]}"
do
    SECRET_NAME="${i}"
    SECRET_VALUE=$(gcloud secrets versions access "latest" --secret=${SECRET_NAME})
    echo $SECRET_VALUE > secret_migrate
    $(gcloud secrets create ${SECRET_NAME} --project [TARGET_PROJECT] --data-file=secret_migrate --labels=environment=test,service="${i}")
done
rm secret_migrate
```

Comment: One suggestion. Instead of using `gcloud config set project`, add the command line argument `--project=REPLACE_WITH_PROJECT_ID`

Answer (score 1):

As of today there is no way to have GCP move the Secret between projects for you.

It's a good feature request that you can file here: https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=784854&pli=1&template=1380926

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have just faced the same need, so I did a script which replicates all versions and labels a secret can have. If a secret or a specific version already exits, it skips it. It can be found in a GitHub Gist (https://gist.github.com/froblesmartin/0af754020d32dbe9e6ad97d896494c22) but I am also copying it here:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

function transform_output_to_array() {
    local output="$1"
    local array=()
    local skip_first=true

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if ${skip_first}; then
            skip_first=false
            continue
        fi
        array+=("${line}")
    done <<< "${output}"

    echo "${array[@]}"
}

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
SOURCE_GCP_PROJECT="your-source-project"
TARGET_GCP_PROJECT="your-target-project"
SECRETS_OUTPUT=$(gcloud secrets list --project=${SOURCE_GCP_PROJECT} --format="csv(name)")
SECRETS_ARRAY=($(transform_output_to_array "${SECRETS_OUTPUT}"))

TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY=$(mktemp -d -p .)
echo "Generated temporary directory: [${TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY}]"

# Loop over the array
for SECRET_NAME in "${SECRETS_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    echo
    echo "Secret name [${SECRET_NAME}]"

    SECRET_VERSIONS_OUTPUT=$(gcloud secrets versions list --project=${SOURCE_GCP_PROJECT} --format="csv(name)" -- ${SECRET_NAME})
    SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY=($(transform_output_to_array "${SECRET_VERSIONS_OUTPUT}"))

    echo "Versions: [${SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY[@]}"]

    SECRET_LABELS=""

    while read -r KEY VALUE; do
        SECRET_LABELS+="${KEY}=${VALUE},"
    done < <(gcloud secrets describe --format="json" -- ${SECRET_NAME} | jq -r '.labels | to_entries | .[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"')

    echo "Labels: [${SECRET_LABELS}]"

    gcloud secrets create --project ${TARGET_GCP_PROJECT} --labels=${SECRET_LABELS} -- ${SECRET_NAME} || \
      echo -e "${RED}Secret [${SECRET_NAME}] creation failed${NC}"

    SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY_LENGTH=${#SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY[@]}
    for ((i=${SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY_LENGTH}-1; i>=0; i--)); do
        echo "Processing version: ${SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY[${i}]}"
        gcloud secrets versions access ${SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY[${i}]} --secret=${SECRET_NAME} --project=${SOURCE_GCP_PROJECT} > ${TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY}/${SECRET_NAME}_${SECRET_VERSION}
        gcloud secrets versions access ${SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY[${i}]} --secret=${SECRET_NAME} --project=${TARGET_GCP_PROJECT} >> /dev/null && \
          { echo -e "${RED}Version [${SECRETS_VERSIONS_ARRAY[${i}]}] already exists${NC}" && continue; }
        gcloud secrets versions add --project ${TARGET_GCP_PROJECT} --data-file=${TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY}/${SECRET_NAME}_${SECRET_VERSION} -- ${SECRET_NAME}
    done
done
```

Answer (score -3):

All "secrets" MUST be decrypted and compiled in order to be processed by a CPU as hardware decryption isn't practical for commercial use. Because of this getting your passwords/configuration (in PLAIN TEXT) is as simple as logging into one of your deployments that has the so called "secrets" (plain text secrets...) and typing 'env' a command used to list all environment variables on most Linux systems.

If your secret is a text file just use the program 'cat' to read the file. I haven't found a way to read these tools from GCP directly because "security" is paramount.

GCP has methods of exec'ing into a running container but you could also look into kubectl commands for this too. I believe the "PLAIN TEXT" secrets are encrypted on googles servers then decrypted when they're put into your cluser/pod.

Comment: This post does not answer the question asked. Either improve the post to actually answer the question or delete it.

Comment: It tells him how to access his secrets.  When you have access to the secrets you can deploy them anywhere. I fail to see how this doesn't answer the question, please explain.

Comment: The poster asked if a mechanism already existed, not how to implement one themselves.

Comment: Yes this answer only gives the access but nothing to do with the migration to other project. My temporary fix is to create them manually in the other project for now until found a solution.